# How Do I Update A Table From A Different SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in a database on my development(local workstation) SQL Server 2008 Express that I have added some records to. Now, I would like to deploy this table to the production SQL Server 2000 located on a server. What is the best was to accomplish this? I want to retain the data from the development instance. Both tables have the exact same structure. Can I use the DTS Import/Export wizard from the production SQL Server 2000 through the SQL Server Enterprise Manager? Does it overwrite tables when importing? Will it handle the different versions of SQL Server?

Comment: Bad idea to develop against SQL Server 2008 when you are going to go to a 2000 prod box. There area alot of syntax changes. Make sure the database you work with is in compatibility mode.

Comment: We expect to go to 2008 soon(fingers crossed). My stuff is so simple it runs on both. Should I have looked for SQL Server 2000 Express and installed it? Is it even available? What would have been a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You development work should result in scripts, not in bits in the database. [There are many advantages in doing so](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/15/version-control-and-your-database/). When you deploy, you run the developed scripts on the productions database. Now that you let the cat out of the bag, your best option is to use export the table and then import it, see [FAQ: How do I import/export data with SQL Express](http://blogs.msdn.com/euanga/archive/2006/07/20/672272.aspx). SQL's own import/export wizard requires SSIS (see [Importing and Exporting Data by Using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx)), which is not part of Express editions.

If the table is reasonable small you can use a distributed query (ie. linked server), but that will require MSDTC because it will be an update, and you may need to configure it.

Comment: It's not difficult to generate the appropriate INSERT script out of the live data in the development database.

Comment: Thanks for steering me in the right direction. As I read your answer the light came on as to how I have been doing this all wrong. I will need to learn a bit of T-SQL but it will be worth it.

Answer (score 3):

One technique is to create a linked server. Check the msdn link  [Linked server - msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx)

Then you can write a single query to do the Update or whatever that has access to tables on both servers.

Comment: I would probably avoid creating a linked server between a dev and production box, at least one that has any kind of write access.  Deployment from one environment to another should be scripted out.

Answer (score 0):

If you have SqlServer Management Studio (not express).  You can use the import and export options to quickly transfer data in and out.  This assumes you can connect to the database from your local machine though.